# how to setup a teambuild

Tags: tfsbuild

How to Setup a Teambuild, i would like to know process of how the build machine has to setup. any proxy settings? how to integrate the build server to TFS server to do builds?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a step-by-step walkthrough on MSDN on how to setup and configure a TFS build server machine.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181711.aspx